# Device not showing in ubuntu-sdk on lxc

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, lxc

I am running ubuntu-sdk in an lxc Ubuntu container (due to it not being available for my host distro) and passing a Nexus 4 running Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-12) with `lxc-device add $(readlink -f /dev/android)`. I can see the device fine using `adb devices` but when I launch ubuntu-sdk, the device does not appear in the devices tab and it disapears from `adb devices` until I restart the adb daemon.

My guess is that ubuntu-sdk is restarting the adb daemon with incorrect permissions, is there a way to make it use the existing adb session? Or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

When the SDK is starting , it indeed does restart the ADB server. There is some problem with ADB sometimes not showing all devices without restarting it.

However your installation is not support BUT you might have a chance to change how the ADB server is starting by modifying the SDK scripts somewhere in:
/usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/device_search

Not sure if the path is correct, the scriptname definately is.

If you find a way that makes that work in and outside the container we probably even can include it.